# Not able to supply right argument to foreach statement

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-ui, foreach

Hello I have 2 html tables. I am using jquery UI to change the position of the table and pass this jquery event arguments through ajax while taking index and item id of the table position so that I can update in the database the current position of the table. Everything is running fine I can pass the parameter. The only mistake I am making is I am not able to take this argument in foreach statement properly. It is generating an error in foreach statement that invalid argument supplied for foreach().Here is my fiddle :[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/13/). I want to pass array but i am passing string in ajax. And not able to do so.I am getting like this when i try to print_r($_POST): Array ( [aktion] => show-widget [widget] => 1 [item] => Fahrzeuge )
Here is my code:
dashboard.js

```
$("#widget_update").sortable({      
      update : function(event, ui) {
          var widget = $('#widget_update').sortable('serialize');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'show-widget','widget':ui.item.index(),'item':ui.item[0].id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#widget').html(data.html);                           
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Error');         
        }
        });
      }
});
```

dashboard.php

```
foreach ($_GET['item'] as $position => $item) :
$sql="Update dashboard_widget_users inner join dashboard_widget on dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget=dashboard_widget.ID
set dashboard_widget_users.position=".$position." 
where dashboard_widget.name='".$item."' and dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user=10";
      $sql_update=mysql_query($sql);      
      endforeach;
```

Comment: The value you are passing to `foreach` has to be an **array**.

Comment: You are sending data via post and receiving via get ;-)

Comment: In firbug i can see the parameter as : aktion show-widget
widget 0
item NEWS   when i try to change the position of table.

Comment: Right. And `NEWS` seems to be a string, not an array. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with a `foreach` loop over a string.

Comment: i am sorry i change it to Post now ;)

Comment: can you please tell me how can i take this parameter and update my database..i thought i can use foreach...

Comment: I would start by not using a deprecated interface anymore. Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: yes but can you please tell me what chanegs i can do in ajax so taht i can pass array and take in foreach loop..

Answer (score 0):

You passed `ui.item[0].id` to your `item` property for your `data`. I think it is passing a `string` instead of an `array` that will be used to your `foreach`.

Try to pass `ui.item`

Hope that helps.

### Answer 2:

Since you already know the `position` and `id`, you could loop them and store data in an `object` before passing to data property. This code may guide you:

```
$("#widget_update").sortable({      
    update : function(event, ui) {
        var widget = $('#widget_update').sortable('serialize'),
            items = [];

        for (var i in ui.item) {
            item = item[i];

            items.push({
                position: i,
                id: item.id
            })
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
            dataType : 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                'aktion': 'show-widget',
                'widget': ui.item.index(), // I'm not sure what is this for
                'item': items
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#widget').html(data.html);                           
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('Error');         
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**In your PHP

```
// print_r($_POST);

foreach ($_POST["item"] as $value) {
    // print_r($value);
    $id = $value["id"];
    $position = $value["position"];
}
```

These codes are not tested but you can see whats happening in there.

Comment: i want to pass array and i tried to make changes u said but its giving an error now..

Comment: Try to `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` and paste here what you get. You can view dumped data via inspect element -> Network (click the url after submit) then navigate to Preview or Response tab

Comment: I am getting like this when i try to print_r($_POST):  Array
(
    [aktion] => show-widget
    [widget] => 1
    [item] => Fahrzeuge
)   I can use simply $_POST as to take into php variable and update it but i think for array i have to use foreach so taht i can always get the updated position and stored in the database

Comment: did you `print_r` using my answer (passing `ui.item`)?

Comment: Hi how can i take the array of both the widget and their position ? right now i am taking the array of wdiget that i am changinf and their positon ..

Comment: yes i try to pass ui.item and getting an error:TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement. 

value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );

Comment: Try to `console.log(ui.item)` or something and build an `object` of positions and ids inside your `js`. Store that on a variable before you pass to `data` property. Or you already know the positions via JS?

Comment: yes i aready know the position from index ..please check the updated question...Right now i am passing only 1 widget and their postion but i want to pass both widget and their updated position in ajax ...do u know how to do that ?

Comment: I will post another answer

Comment: hi i tried your code  i am getting error item is not defined ?

Comment: You don't need to use that actual code.. Just use the logic/flow of the code. The goal is to save each widgets position and id to an `array` and each item object will have an `id` and `position` property. Now, in your PHP, it will automatically get the `item` as array so you can use it on your `foreach`